# Sophomore dream, sine, and the golden ratio

Tags: inequalities

It's an inequality I found nice let me propose it :
$$\int_0^\infty \sin\left(x^{-x}\right) \, dx<\varphi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} \tag I$$

---

My attempt :

First of all I recall two facts :

### Fact 1

$$\int_{0}^{1} x^{-x}\ dx = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{-n}$$

---

### Fact 2:

Let $0\leq x\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$ then we have :

$$\sin\left(x\right)\leq x-\frac{x^{3}}{3!}+\frac{x^{5}}{5!}$$

Unfortunately it works on $J=[0,1]$ not on $[0,\infty]$

---

### Edit :

We have the following inequalities :

For $1\leq x\leq 2$ :

### $$e^{-\left(\frac{x^{0.5}\left(x-1\right)}{2^{0.5}}\right)\cdot2\ln\left(2\right)}\geq x^{-x}$$

For $2\leq x\leq 6$ :

### $$e^{\left(-\left(x-1\right)^{\frac{92}{100}}x^{0.5}\cdot2^{0.5}\ln\left(2\right)\right)}\geq x^{-x}$$

For $0.5\leq x\leq 1$ :

### $$e^{\left(\left(1-x\right)(x)^{0.57}\cdot2^{0.57}\ln\left(2\right)\right)}\geq x^{-x}$$

---

How to show it $(I)$ ?

Comment: As a side comment, much of the integral is small with respect to $\phi$. Indeed $x^{-x} \le e^{-x}$ for $x \ge e$, so that $\int_e^{\infty} x^{-x} \le \int_e^{\infty} e^{-x} = e^{-e} \simeq 0,066$. The same argument with $1+\epsilon$ in place of $e$ yields $\int_1^{\infty} x^{-x} \le 1$, but maybe there is a better inequality for this interval.

Comment: @AndreaMarino Thanks ! I have got $\left(e^{\frac{-e}{\left(e-1\right)^{2}}\cdot\left(\ln\left(x^{2}+e-1\right)-e^{-1}\right)^{\left(2\right)}}\left(e^{-1}\right)^{-e^{-1}}\right)\geq x^{-x}$ for $1\leq x\leq 2$.

Comment: Numerically your integral is approximately $1.612215152$, so you just need to approximate it with a provable accuracy better than about $0.0058$.

Comment: I would say this allows to throw away the integral from 6 on, since $\int_6^{\infty} x^{-x} \le 6^{-6} \approx 0,000021$, which is less than 1% of the accuracy we need.